# struct.pack() failing with int > 127

Tags: python, sockets, struct.pack

Why is

```
struct.pack("!bbbb", 0x2, r, g, b)
```

failing in my python code when r, g, or b is > 127?

I know that the "b" means the size of a given value is 1 byte according to the struct docs, but why does it fail with values over 127?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters), `b` stands for:

> signed char

which means its valid range is [-128, 127]. And that's what the error messages says explicitly:

```
>>> struct.pack("!bbbb", 0x2, 127, 127, 128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: byte format requires -128 <= number <= 127
```

Using `B` yields no error:

```
>>> struct.pack("!bbbB", 0x2, 127, 127, 128)
'\x02\x7f\x7f\x80'
```